# Activity must either be declared asbtract or implement abstract method when using callback

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Hello can I ask why I am getting this error? I tried to make the public class admin into an abstract one but the app won't initiate and would result into an error. Other solutions when clicking alt+ enter says i must enter an implementation but I don't know what to do with that. anywhere here are my code

**MainActivity**

```
public class AdminActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MemberDetailAdapter.Callback {
private DrawerLayout mdrawerl;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mtoggle;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private com.google.firebase.ikuzou.database.MemberDetailAdapter mAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mdrawerl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mtoggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mdrawerl,R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mdrawerl.addDrawerListener(mtoggle);
    NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv) ;
    mtoggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showAddEditDialog(null);
        }
    });

    mAdapter = new com.google.firebase.ikuzou.database.MemberDetailAdapter(AdminActivity.this);
    RecyclerView view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    view.setHasFixedSize(true);
    view.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**Adapter one**

```
public class MemberDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemberDetailAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<User1> mUser;
private Callback mCallback;
private DatabaseReference userref;


public MemberDetailAdapter(Callback callback) {
    mCallback = callback;
    mUser = new ArrayList<>();
    userref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Accounts").child("Users");
    userref.addChildEventListener(new UserChildEventListener());
```

**using the callback inside my adapter**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final User1 user = mUser.get(position);
    holder.mNameTextView.setText(user.getName());
    holder.mEmailTextView.setText(user.getEmail());
    holder.mDateTextView.setText(user.getDate());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCallback.onEdit(user);
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            remove(mUser.get(position));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend an abstract class, and don't make that class abstract, it must provide an implementation for all the abstract methods in the abstract super class.

Your problem is that there is an abstract method in your parent class that you are not implementing in your concrete class.

Compare the methods you have in your concrete class, with the methods in your abstract class, and you should find a difference there.

Comment: You need to implement each and every abstract method from these two sources (and their parents) 'extends AppCompatActivity implements MemberDetailAdapter.Callback'. The implemented methods are inherited, the abstract ones not

Comment: @Yamiess if you found the issue, could you mark any of the answers as "accepted"? that way it won't show up in the unresolved questions any longer

Comment: I need to wait for a minute

Answer (score 1):

You should have a voice in the code menu that says "Overrides methods" or "Implement methods". Try with these entries to find which methods you must still implement